# Is there a way to add Age header in nginx when using proxy caching?

Tags: caching, nginx

It seems that this is not formally supported:

https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/146

quote from linked ticket:

> As far as I understand RFC 2616 a HTTP 1.1 proxy server must send an 'Age' header for responses generated from its own cache (see ​http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.6). However nginx 1.1.18 seems not to send this header in case it sends a reply generated from its cache and 'proxy_http_version' is set to '1.1'.

Does anyone know of a work-around? this header seems to be required by the spec so I'm surprised that there's no way to add it.

Comment: Up. I have the same question. Is there something new since 2 years ?